# Facebook live video api issue

Tags: facebook, iframe, live-streaming, live-video

How I can change Facebook iframe heigth and width

I am using this api >> [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/105520095293517/live_videos?fields=comments,embed_html,status,stream_url&access_token=%5C\](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/105520095293517/live_videos?fields=comments,embed_html,status,stream_url&access_token=%5C%5C)<.....access_token_here....>&status=SCHEDULED_UNPUBLISHED

I am getting this output {

```
 "data": [
    {
      "status": "VOD",
      "stream_url": "rtmps://edgetee-upload-del1-1.xx.fbcdn.net:443/rtmp/256124903603243?s_bl=1&s_sw=0&s_tids=1&s_vt=usr&a=AbzNZRpTzhDFN9V7",
      "secure_stream_url": "rtmps://edgetee-upload-del1-1.xx.fbcdn.net:443/rtmp/256124903603243?s_bl=1&s_sw=0&s_tids=1&s_vt=usr&a=AbzNZRpTzhDFN9V7",
      "embed_html": "<iframe allow=\"autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"1280\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?width=720&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F255437947005272%2Fvideos%2F248902591019770\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" width=\"720\"></iframe>",
      "id": "256124903603243"
    }
}
```

in this output we can see in iframe we have height and width.
How we can get 500px iframe height

I enabled all permission and tried to pass fields.
please confirm How we can solve this problem.

I tried to change the height and width by Javascript
but I think, it's not good.

Please help me

Comment: Write code that directly modifies the `embed_html` value after you fetch it.